# What is the best way to store stock history data

Tags: time-series, stock

I mean to build a system to support below query to my DataBase

```
get1minData(stock, beginDate, endDate)
get5minData(stock, beginDate, endDate)
get30minData(stock, beginDate, endDate)
get60minData(stock, beginDate, endDate)
.....
```

The input for the system is second level data, which means I have to aggregate my data for different API.

What database should I use? I heard a lot about time series DB. Is this a good option?
Or just use MySQL and write some fancy query to achieve this goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I store 10 years of FX tick data (and growing) for the majors (and about 6 years of tick data for 30+ crosses) in a postgres db. It is a little more than 60GB with index on the timestamp. With 8GB memory it flies on my laptop. Since I need 5M/15M/30M/1H/4H/D1 candles quite often I have other tables to store them ie they are calculated once. It is very convenient since I can slurp it in to R.

Comment: Thanks! I think I will also go with a traditional RDBMS, since my data is not HUGE.